# Why is my callback message getting executed in another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

1. Why does the `_OnStateChanged` method gets executed in another thread then an instance of `MainWindow`?
2. Is there another way to call `myRichTextBox.AppendText()` without having to use delegates?

   ```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window {
   private static PureSocketClusterSocket _socket 
   //[...]

   public MainWindow() {       
       //[...]
       Debug.WriteLine("MainWindow() thread Id: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
       _socket = new PureSocketClusterSocket(...); 
       _socket += _OnStateChanged; 
       //[...]
   }

   private void _OnStateChanged(WebSocketState newState, WebSocketState prevState) {
       Debug.WriteLine("_OnStateChanged() Thread Id: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
       myRichTextBox.AppendText(...); 
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: I use WPF for many years. I think that the best way is create a View, and Bind the UI to it. INotifyPropertyChanged, or simply use https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => myRichTextBox.AppendText(...));`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I still dont understand, why the callback functions are getting executed in another thread.

Comment: You might take a look at the source code...

Comment: Because sockets uses their own threads. So it is up to you to call `Invoke` (or uses other alternatives) if you want to communicate with the UI as necessary. You have to be aware that cross-thread calls are expensive and minimize those if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [PureSocketClusterSocket](https://github.com/coinigy/PureSocketCluster/blob/master/src/PureSocketCluster/PureSocketClusterSocket.cs) uses [PureWebSocket](https://github.com/coinigy/PureWebSockets/blob/master/src/PureWebsockets/PureWebSocket.cs) which uses [ClientWebSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket(v=vs.110).aspx)

ClientWebSocket will raise events asynchronously (on threads from a pool) so the developer can decide which thread should handle the result. Blocking the UI thread to wait for a response from the network is a bad idea as it will lock the UI

2. You will need to use a delegate (dispatcher call) to get back to the UI.